# How to make the confirmation box return true for javascript sweetalert2

Tags: javascript, sweetalert, sweetalert2

I want to change my alert box to Sweet Alert2 (https://sweetalert2.github.io/). After clicking the "Ok" button on the Confirm alert window, nothing seems to be happening. I can't seem to figure out what's wrong or how to solve the problem. my codes are as follows:

Html:

```
<a href="functionalities/removeIncoming.php?incId=<?php echo $incID; ?>"> 
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="delBtn" onclick="validateRemove(event);">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-book" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</button>
</a>
```

Javascript:

```
function validateRemove(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    swal({
  title: "Are you sure you want to archive this entry?",
  type: 'warning',
  showCancelButton: true,
  confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
  cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
  confirmButtonText: 'Yes',
  cancelButtonText: "No"
}).then(function () {
  swal(
    'Archived',
    'Your file has been Archived.',
    'success'
  )
})
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
onclick="confirm1();"

    function confirm1()
        {

            swal({
                title: 'Are you sure?',
                text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
                type: 'warning',
                showCancelButton: true,
                confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
                cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
                confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!',
                cancelButtonText: 'No, cancel!',
                confirmButtonClass: 'btn btn-success',
                cancelButtonClass: 'btn btn-danger',
                buttonsStyling: false
            }).then(function () {
                swal(
                  'Deleted!',
                  'Your file has been deleted.',
                  'success'
                )
               //success method
            }, function (dismiss) {
                // dismiss can be 'cancel', 'overlay',
                // 'close', and 'timer'
                if (dismiss === 'cancel') {
                    swal(
                      'Cancelled',
                      'Your imaginary file is safe :)',
                      'error'
                    )                
                }
            })      
        }
```